# Where can I find the package Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

After a fresh Xamarin Install I get the following error while trying to compile a freshly created Xamarin Forms Portable Droid project without changes to the generated code:

Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\Markus\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.0.1.3\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist.    XamarinFormsApp05.Droid

Where can I get the missing files?

Comment: Had the same issue. Found solution here https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/resolving-library-installation-errors/#Manually_Downloading_m2repository

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The package name `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat` is the name of the Xamarin version of this java package. It's available via NuGet. 
Ensure that your build and support libraries are up to date (see instruction below).
After that you may have to delete `...\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.0.1.3`and rebuild everything. If this doesn't help, try to update the NuGet packages of your project.

**Hint:** You should always keep the installed libraries and **build tools** up to date. Else it will end up in a non responding VS or build problems, sometimes.

Open the Android SDK manager via the toolbar icon or `Tools > Android > SDK Manager` or `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\SDK Manager.exe`.

[image: VS Android SDK Manager Icon]

There you can install the support libraries and update other stuff.

[image]

Comment: I approve the use of freehand circle.

Comment: In the second image? ;)

Comment: Haha yes those are great circles too!

Comment: Deleting the Folder 23.0.1.3  from Path ...\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.0.1.3 Was the solution. It got filled on the next build correctly. !!! Just a warning: Updating to the newest Xamarin NuGet Packages screwed up everything - at least on my machine. After the update I could not compile any project in the solution any more. Also the Windows and shared projects presented compile errors - e.g.: about missing properties in the ....designer.cs files...